# How to get contents from my Instagram profile?

Tags: php, regex

I have made a script, that reads my Instagram profile information by downloading the pagecontent, and then searching for strings in it.
It worked very well, but some months later, the script is sooo slow and results in a white screen. As you can see, I am trying to display 8 values from my Instagram profile. But only if I echo only 2 values at one time, my page loads (but slow) and does not end in a whitescreen of death.

I already tried to display all PHP-Errors, but nothing. All values are correct, if I only display one value.

Is `preg_match` too slow for 8 values? Are there faster alternatives to do that?

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function GetIGInformation($type)
{

    $raw = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/MyUserName");

    if ($type == "1") {
        if (preg_match('/"profile_pic_url_hd":"(.*?)","requested_by_viewer":/', $raw, $ProfilePic2)) {
            return $ProfilePic2[1];
        } else {
            return "https://instagram.fyyz1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/6a15ea059743aabab5376f3d6377a51a/5D5480F1/t51.2885-19/44884218_345707102882519_2446069589734326272_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fyyz1-1.fna.fbcdn.net";
        }

    }

    if ($type == "2") {
        if (preg_match('/"edge_followed_by":{"count":(.*?)},"followed_by_viewer":/', $raw, $Follower2)) {
            return $Follower2[1];
        } else {
            return "0";
        }
    }

    if ($type == "3") {
        if (preg_match('/"edge_owner_to_timeline_media":{"count":(.*?),"page_info":/', $raw, $Posts2)) {
            return $Posts2[1];
        } else {
            return "No posts";
        }
    }

    if ($type == "4") {
        if (preg_match('/"edge_follow":{"count":(.*?)},"follows_viewer"/', $raw, $Followed2)) {
            return $Followed2[1];
        } else {
            return "Nobody";
        }
    }

    if ($type == "5") {
        if (preg_match('/"external_url":"(.*?)","external_url_linkshimmed":/', $raw, $Website2)) {
            return $Website2[1];
        } else {
            return "No website";
        }
    }

    if ($type == "6") {
        if (preg_match('/"username":"(.*?)","connected_fb_page":/', $raw, $Username2)) {
            return $Username2[1];
        } else {
            return "No username";
        }
    }

    if ($type == "7") {
        if (preg_match('/"display_url":"(.*?)","edge_liked_by":/', $raw, $BilderVorhanden2)) {
            return "Yes";
        } else {
            return "No";
        }
    }

    if ($type == "8") {

        if (preg_match('/"biography":"(.*?)","blocked_by_viewer":/', $raw, $Biographie2)) {
            return $Biographie2[1];
        } else {
            return "No biography";
        }
    }

}

echo GetIGInformation(1);
echo "\n";
echo GetIGInformation(2);
echo "\n";
echo GetIGInformation(3);
echo "\n";
echo GetIGInformation(4);
echo "\n";
echo GetIGInformation(5);
echo "\n";
echo GetIGInformation(6);
echo "\n";
echo GetIGInformation(7);
echo "\n";
echo GetIGInformation(8);
echo "\n";
```

Comment: You’re hitting instagram every time you run the function. That could get costly. And, if for some reason you get throttled or denied access, your script will wait until it finally times out. It would be better to capture the data once and then pass the data to the function.

Comment: Hello, I have added the file_get_contents on top of the file (not in my function anymore) but same issue..

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using curl methods:

```
function curlGetContents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return htmlspecialchars($data);
}

$raw = curlGetContents("https://www.instagram.com/MyUserName/");
```

Answer (score 0):

> No, `preg_match` is not a slow function.

There should be some other issues. I'm not really sure, if this might solve your problem, maybe add `memory_limit` to `-1` such as:

```
// error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
set_time_limit(0);

function GetIGInformation($type)
{

    $raw = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/MyUserName");

    if ($type == "1") {
        if (preg_match('/"profile_pic_url_hd":"(.*?)","requested_by_viewer":/', $raw, $ProfilePic2)) {
            return $ProfilePic2[1];
        } else {
            return "https://instagram.fyyz1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/6a15ea059743aabab5376f3d6377a51a/5D5480F1/t51.2885-19/44884218_345707102882519_2446069589734326272_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fyyz1-1.fna.fbcdn.net";
        }

    }

    if ($type == "2") {
        if (preg_match('/"edge_followed_by":{"count":(.*?)},"followed_by_viewer":/', $raw, $Follower2)) {
            return $Follower2[1];
        } else {
            return "0";
        }
    }

    if ($type == "3") {
        if (preg_match('/"edge_owner_to_timeline_media":{"count":(.*?),"page_info":/', $raw, $Posts2)) {
            return $Posts2[1];
        } else {
            return "No posts";
        }
    }

    if ($type == "4") {
        if (preg_match('/"edge_follow":{"count":(.*?)},"follows_viewer"/', $raw, $Followed2)) {
            return $Followed2[1];
        } else {
            return "Nobody";
        }
    }

    if ($type == "5") {
        if (preg_match('/"external_url":"(.*?)","external_url_linkshimmed":/', $raw, $Website2)) {
            return $Website2[1];
        } else {
            return "No website";
        }
    }

    if ($type == "6") {
        if (preg_match('/"username":"(.*?)","connected_fb_page":/', $raw, $Username2)) {
            return $Username2[1];
        } else {
            return "No username";
        }
    }

    if ($type == "7") {
        if (preg_match('/"display_url":"(.*?)","edge_liked_by":/', $raw, $BilderVorhanden2)) {
            return "Yes";
        } else {
            return "No";
        }
    }

    if ($type == "8") {

        if (preg_match('/"biography":"(.*?)","blocked_by_viewer":/', $raw, $Biographie2)) {
            return $Biographie2[1];
        } else {
            return "No biography";
        }
    }

}

echo GetIGInformation(1);
echo "\n";
echo GetIGInformation(2);
echo "\n";
echo GetIGInformation(3);
echo "\n";
echo GetIGInformation(4);
echo "\n";
echo GetIGInformation(5);
echo "\n";
echo GetIGInformation(6);
echo "\n";
echo GetIGInformation(7);
echo "\n";
echo GetIGInformation(8);
echo "\n";
```

and see what happens.

- Maybe, some variables/policies may have been changed. You might `var_dump();` your variables step by step, to check where the problem might be.
- You can also set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to see, if any warnings/errors might return.

Maybe run this command in your terminal, if using macOS, or find equivalent of the command for other Linux/Windows:

```
 php -f /path/to/your/php/file.php
```

and see what might return.

Comment: Hello, thank you so far. But the page still loads very long and ends up in a whitescreen.. I also put the file_get_contents function on top of the file, to prevent calling it too often, but nothing..